# Rails 3.2.x has_many, through (3 models) calls nil id before create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2, nested-attributes, has-many-through

Here is what I am dealing with, but first a bit of background on what needs to be done. There are 3 models: Patients -- Appointments -- Procedures

Within these 3 models there are two views Procedures -- Patients

Of these 2 views I would like to schedule Appointments through the Patients (show) view. Which in essence will create a new appointment for the patient in view (specifically the patient.id in view).

Here is the code for the models

```rb
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address1, :address2, :city, :comment, :email, :first_name, :init_date, :init_time, :last_name, :mobile, :notes, :phone, :state, :zip

  has_many :appointments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :procedures, through: :appointments
```

```rb
class Procedure < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment, :occurence, :procedure, :procedure_code, :procedure_price, :procedure_time, :visits
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
```

```rb
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :appointment_date, :appointment_notes, :appointment_time, :procedure_id
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :procedure
```

Here is the controller for appointments as well as the routes.rb inclusion of appointments (but just that line)

```rb
resources :appointments, only: [:create, :destroy, :edit, :update]
```

```rb
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
include PatientsHelper
before_filter :signed_in_user

def create
    @current_patient = @patient.id
    @appointment = @current_patient.appointments.build(params[:appointment])
    if @appointment.save
        flash[:success] = "Appointment scheduled!"
        redirect_to patient_path(@current_patient)
    else
        render 'create'
    end
end
```

```rb
module PatientsHelper

def current_patient=(patient)
    @current_patient = patient
end

def current_patient
    @current_patient
end

def current_patient?(patient)
    patient == current_patient
end
end
```

So that is the setup, I am receiving the following rspec error in the patients_controller. Have tested @appointment = @current_patient.appointments.build(params[:appointment]) in console by first defining an id for @current_patient = Patient.first. That works and a build happens as it should. The error:

Failures:

```
1) Appointment Pages appointment creation with invalid information should not create an appointment
 Failure/Error: expect { click_button "Schedule procedure" }.not_to change(Appointment,
 RuntimeError:
   Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
 # ./app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb:6:in `create'
 # (eval):2:in `click_button'
 # ./spec/requests/appointment_pages_spec.rb:17:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/requests/appointment_pages_spec.rb:17:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Appointment Pages appointment creation with invalid information error messages 
 Failure/Error: before { click_button "Schedule procedure" }
 RuntimeError:
   Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
 # ./app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb:6:in `create'
 # (eval):2:in `click_button'
 # ./spec/requests/appointment_pages_spec.rb:22:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) Appointment Pages appointment creation with valid information should create a micropost
 Failure/Error: expect { click_button "Schedule procedure" }.to change(Appointment,
 RuntimeError:
   Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
 # ./app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb:6:in `create'
 # (eval):2:in `click_button'
 # ./spec/requests/appointment_pages_spec.rb:36:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/requests/appointment_pages_spec.rb:36:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It would seem that I am not properly defining @current_patient = @patient.id... or rather the current patient in view is not carrying over/through to the appointments form. Where do I need to define the current patient to carry that id through to the form create method of @current_patient.appointments.build?

Comment: what do you want to do with this line `@current_patient = @patient.id`? You set an ID number for `@current_patient`, now `@current_patient` is a number, so you could not call `appointments` method. Also, I think you need to render new action when `@appointment` was not saved, not create action.

Comment: Because this is going through the Patients view pages I want to schedule a new appointment using patient.appointments.build, do not want to create it via new action.
In my browser the form is displayed via the app.dev/patients/3 (where 3 is the current patient view). This is where the appointments scheduling should take place.  My appointments model, perhaps its controller does not know the current patient. This is what I believe to be the problem. Not sure how to write the appropriate code to define "current_patient in view". I suspect it is similar to console @current_patient = Patient.first

Comment: okay, if you want to get current patient has ID is 3, like in your link above, try this: `@current_patient = Patient.where(id: params[:id])` in your create action, the `params[:id]` is id of patient in your current patient view. In console, you set `@current_patient` to **a Patient object**, otherwise in your create action, you set it to **a number**, so it just worked in console,

Comment: plugged it in and...
now it creates a new error..
       NoMethodError:
       undefined method `'appointments' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation
     # ./app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb:8:in 'create'`

Not sure where the associations are breaking, but it seems that the Patient is found (by Patient I mean all patient attributes not just id) if I understand your code correctly.

Comment: oh, sorry, I forgot that `Patient.where(id: params[:id])` return an array of objects, add `first` method to it to get current patient, so it should be `Patient.where(id: params[:id]).first` :D

Comment: that makes sense here is what I receive now after the change to @current_patient. `NoMethodError:
       undefined method 'appointments' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb:7:in 'create'` any thoughts? Does this have anything to do with the fact that I am using the form in the http://app.dev/patient/1 (show model)? Would prefer not to build a new view just for a simple appointment scheduling form. Thanks for your responses Kien.

Comment: The `params[:id]` will return the id of patient in your show view, with this link http://app.dev/patient/1, it will return 1. If you have a `show` action, try set `@current_patient = Patient.where(id: params[:id]).first` in it.

Comment: Okay. But it seems to be back to nil class. Where to look next for the build to work, any thoughts based on that error message?

Comment: You need to put it in `Patient` controller. You don't need to create `Appointment` controller. You can create a appointment form for patient by create new action. You need to follow the Rails way, it will be easier for you. You can learn more in this [Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what I was looking for but made this work-around.

Using the following was able to get this to save accordingly. *Still cannot find out why I am unable to pull the Patient from the URL -- example would be app.dev/patients/2 -- where patient information is pulling id 2*... but now I am able to save the Appointment using what I suspect is a rather crude method.

1. In the form I added a hidden field which pulls the appropriate patient_id
2. In Appointments controller, added to attr_accessible :patient_id
3. In appointments_controller

   ```
   def create
   @appointment = Appointment.new(params[:appointment])
   @current_patient = @appointment.patient_id
   if @appointment.save
       flash[:success] = "Appointment scheduled!"
       redirect_to patient_path(@current_patient)
   else
       render 'patients/show'
   end
   end
   ```

`render 'patients/show'` remains broken but will leave that for another thread. Thank you all for your help and guidance.  Again, I suspect that the render call has to do with the same problem currently plaguing my access to current_patient direct from the appointments_controller model.